# What Apple System Monitor/Integer BASIC ROM features were removed in the Applesoft II/Autostart ROM?

Tags: apple-ii

In spring of 1978, Apple took the updated 6502 BASIC from Microsoft,
fixed some bugs and added some new commands, and released it as
[Applesoft II](https://apple2history.org/history/ah16/#05). This was soon released as a ROM set (shipped
standard with the Apple II+) that replaced the Integer BASIC ROM.

There were various other non-BASIC-related features in the Integer
BASIC ROM, such as the miniassembler, that were lost when this change
was made. Excactly what features were lost?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Page references below refer to the [*Apple II Reference Manual*, 1979
edition](https://archive.org/details/Apple_II_Reference_Manual_1979_Apple/page/n80).

As well as Integer BASIC itself, the following machine-language
features were lost:

- The miniassembler (p.49), allowing one to type in 6502 opcodes that
  it would assemble into memory. (The format was the same as the
  monitor's `L` "list" command printed.) While it didn't support
  symbols or labels, it did let you give absolute addresses to branch
  instructions for which it would calculate the proper relative
  offsets. (The miniassembler was started from the monitor with
  `F666G`, and you could go back to the monitor with `$FF69G`.)
- Monitor step `S` and trace `T` commands (p.51). `S` would print a
  disassembly of the next instruction, execute it, and then print the
  registers. `T` would execute instructions continuously, printing the
  disassembly before and registers after each instruction, until it
  hit a `BRK` instruction or the user pressed RESET.
- [SWEET16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWEET16), a byte-code interpreter for a simple 16-bit virtual
  machine. This provides a more compact, albeit slower, way of
  manipulating 16-bit data than using 6502 assembly language directly.
- Some simple machine-language floating point routines. These are
  described in detail on pp. 110-117 of the Call-A.P.P.L.E.
  publication [The WOZPAK II](https://web.archive.org/web/20120311044310/www.applefritter.com/files/Call-APPLE%20Woz%20Pak%202%201979.pdf). They appear to be similar to,
  possibly the same as, the ones published in the [August 1976
  issue](https://archive.org/details/dr_dobbs_journal_vol_01/page/n208) of *Dr. Dobb's Journal*.

Additionally, Integer BASIC was small enough that it left two 2K ROM
sockets free. One of these could be filled with a ROM sold by Apple
called ["Programmer's Aid #1](https://archive.org/details/programmers-aid-1), which would also have to be
removed if upgrading an Apple II; the Apple II+ lacked a free socket
for this ROM. As well some utilities specific to Integer BASIC (for
renumbering lines, appending programs to each other, and verifying
Integer BASIC programs on tape) it contained the following routines
useful for machine-language programming:

- Verify saved machine-language code or data on tape.
- A relocator for machine-language code, to automatically translate
  addresses to allow the code to run at a different location.
- A RAM test utility.
- A machine-language routine to generate musical tones.
- High-resoulution graphics routines (though probably not a huge loss
  given that Applesoft has similar routines).

Comment: Actually, it seems the miniassembler and step/trace commands were added back in some version of the Apple IIc ROM. At some point I'll research this further and update the answer to discuss this, unless someone else posts an answer about that here first.